# Linux writing to process' own executable file at runtime

Tags: c, linux, runtime, executable

I'd like to be able to store some configuration information in the char array inside the executable file (C program). And I need to modify that array's contents at the runtime.
But I can't open the file from the process.
So... Is it possible, and if it is - what's the trick?
Many thanks in advance.

[1] The question is HOW TO DO IT and **NOT** is it a good idea?

[2] I want to WRITE TO PROCESS' OWN EXEC at runtime just beacause I'm curious how to do that. Let's think about it as a bit o hacking.

Comment: The executable file is on disk, while your program is loaded in memory. While running, any change to the disk version of the file will not affect the running program. Also, if you have an array in the executable, you probably mean like a global variable or something? In that case, you just access it and change it!

Comment: Thanks! That's right, it a global char array. The problem is the segfault I get. I just found the array offset with "string -tx a.out" and hardcoded it in the program, that I should fseek() and fwrite(). But I can't even open the exec file for writing...

Comment: Do not do this. Have an ASCII configuration file instead. This has the advantage in that you can have multiple configuation files and also it enables one to easily see the configuration that the executable is using when things stop working

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The goal is writing to the exec thought...

Comment: Again, like I said, getting the offset of the array in the file is completely irrelevant to its address in memory.

Comment: As I need to write to the exec file, and NOT in the memory of the process, it should work

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
With fork() + execl() combination I make a copy of the executable, modify it without any problems, and then with fork + execl mv I replace the original executable with the modified one.

Comment: Worked on RHEL as described - fork() the child, system() copy, write, replace - nice workaround for error 26 - "text file busy".

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the executable file is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. The easiest thing here is to use a config file, and read from that into your char array.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I'm just curious how can I do that because I find the idea of storing variable configuration info in the exec file rather interesting. It's just something unusual and kind of opportunity to learn more about linux. Obviously it's a bad idea in most cases, but my goal is to do so. If you have some ideas on how it can be done, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that it's a bad idea, I won't bother saying it again.

You better do some reading about executable file formats. The file is probably in ELF format, but you can check it with the `file` command.

In general, a file is built in sections, and each variable has an offset within the section.
The `nm` command can tell you the section and offset for a given symbol.
Each section starts at a given offset within the file. I think the `objdump` command can find these offset.

It won't work for symbols in the BSS section (uninitialized static variables) - the values of these isn't stored in the file - just the fact that they should be allocated when loading.

Once you have these offsets, all is simple - add them, open, seek, write, close.

Comment: Thank you. I've already found all the offsets I need. The problem is I can't event fopen() process' ELF file, it return NULL every time I try to do it...

Comment: I guess the file can't be opened because it's already opened for read by the running process. I don't know if you can override it.